# Are Packaged Apps Usable in the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I just stumbled across the new Chrome Packaged Apps page (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/apps/about_apps.html)

I really, really want to use this for an app, like NOW. However, to test the apps you have to manually enable experimental extensions in chrome.

Will I be able to submit an app that uses these experimental extensions, and will users be able to use them right now?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, you can package an app and self-host it (and tell your users to set the appropriate command-line flags to allow the experimental APIs), but the Web Store as a rule does not accept anything that uses experimental APIs.

Comment: Thanks, I see now in the chrome://flags it has that notice. I guess the new packaged apps announcement was just released yesterday so I assume it'll go stable in a few months...

Comment: Just expanded my original comment to a full answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can package any app you make and self-host it; just make sure to tell your users to set the appropriate command-line flag to allow the experimental APIs (`--enable-experimental-extension-apis`).  The Web Store, however, does not accept anything that uses experimental APIs.  From the [`chrome.experimental` docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.html):

> ...the Chrome Web Store doesn't allow you to upload extensions that use experimental APIs.

Feel free to start developing your app now, though.  With any luck, by the time you're done with development, the APIs you need will be stable (and hopefully they won't have changed *too* much).  Sometimes experimental APIs can disappear outright, but I'd bet that the APIs that Google mentions explicitly on their packaged app page are here to stay.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, based on the polished nature of the Packaged Apps docs in trunk, I'm guessing this isn't going to just disappear...but you never know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no plan to have Chrome Web Store accept apps that use experimental APIs.

Currently, even if you don't use experimental APIs in your (new) Chrome Packaged App, you won't be able to publish it, since the new Chrome Packaged App is in developer preview.

So, the plan is to move the experimental APIs out of experimental state when we are confident they are stable enough. Hopefully, when CWS starts accepting the new Chrome Packaged Apps, most of today's experimental APIs will not be experimental anymore. To speed up this process of API stabilizing, your feedback on these APIs is very valuable. Please, use http://crbug.com if you find bugs.

Comment: Can you help me understand: how do users install Chrome Packaged Apps?Are Chrome Packaged Apps still experimental?

Comment: Users install them from the Chrome Web Store (CWS). They are not experimental anymore, but are in developer preview mode. What this means is that users cannot find them in CWS search or browse, so you are only able to install a Packaged App if you know the direct URL of it.